# Checking to see if input is binary and contains two 1s

Tags: python

I need some advice for this challenge. The requirements are to see if the input is valid (i.e. only 0s and 1s, no spaces, and no letters) and accepted (contains two 1s). Then, if the input is valid and accepted, translate the binary into decimal. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#Examples of invalid binary numbers: abc 10102011 10101FF 
#0000 1111 (note:contains a space)
#Examples of valid, rejected binary numbers: 00000000 1111 01110000001
#Examples of valid, accepted binary numbers: 1000001 11000000 1111

binary = str(input("Enter a binary number: "))
binary_list = list(binary)
valid = True
accepted = True
convert = ""
var = binary_list.count('1')

for character in binary_list:
  if (character != '1') and (character != '0'):
    valid = False


for character in binary_list:
  if (var != 2):
    accepted = False


if (valid == True and accepted == True):
  print("Input", binary ,"is valid and accepted")
  convert = int(binary, 2)
  print ("The number is ", convert)
elif (valid == False):
  print ("Input was invalid")
elif (valid == True and accepted == False):
  print ("Input was rejected")
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the for loops to do what I want. The first says everything is invalid or lets characters and binary with spaces through.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the first loop change the condition of valid to false if any of the items in the list are not 1s or 0s. In the second loop, I want the condition of accepted changed to false if the count of 1s is not equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set`s to check if the input only contains `0`'s and `1`'s.

```
>>> set("1101101000100001001010101")
{'0', '1'}
```

No matter what the result is, it should only contain some subset of `{'0', '1'}`. (There's a chance it won't have one or the other.) We can use the `set.issubset()` method to check this. (Note the `2` in the second example.)

```
>>> set("11010001").issubset(('0', '1'))
True
>>> set("11010201").issubset(('0', '1'))
False
```

Finally, like you found, you can use `str.count()` to figure out if there are exactly two `1`'s.

```
>>> "1001".count('1')
2
```

Here's the entire code block.

```
if not set(binary).issubset(('0', '1')):
    print("Input was invalid binary.")
elif binary.count('1') != 2:
    print("Input was rejected.")
else:
    print("Input", binary, "was valid and accepted!")
```

Note the reordering of the statements; rather than first checking for entire validity and otherwise trying to determine points of failure, we can check for individual fail cases with `if`/`elif`s, and then place the success case afterwards in the `else` block.

---

Edit: If you would like to keep using the strategy that you outlined in your code example, you can add `break` in the `if` block of the first `for` loop, to stop searching after a fail case was found. The second `for` loop is also unnecessary, as you are not using the `character` at all, and it can be removed (keeping the `if` block "outside").

Also, note that the conversion from `binary` to `binary_list` is unnecessary, as `str`ings may be iterated over and have the `.count()` method, as well.

```
for character in binary:
    if character != '1' and character != '0':
        valid = False
        break

if var != 2:
    accepted = False
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I tried both strategies and they solve the challenge.